# Suppose that $\sec(\theta)=\frac{5}{3}$ and $\sin(\theta)<0$ find the following:

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am looking for some help with the following questions I am a little lost. It has been sometime before I worked with trig.

Suppose that $\sec(\theta)=\frac{5}{3}$ and $\sin(\theta)<0$ find the following:

1. $\tan(2\theta)$
2. $\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$
3. $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: Find cos first, the use Pythagoras to find sin.

Comment: could you show me how to do that? I will accept the answer

Comment: Cos = 1/sec, so ... Pythagoras tells you it is a 3, 4, 5 triangle. Look up double angle and half angle formulas. I am giving hints, not doing what looks like your homework.

Comment: Or a $3, -4, 5$ triangle since $\sin\theta<0$.

Comment: @Peter it is actually for tutoring a student but i cant seem to remember it

Comment: Revise signs of trig functions in each quadrant. Draw unit circle, x=3/5,y=4/5. You have 4th quadrant angle. Draw rough positions of double angle and half angle. Recall you have 2 possible half angles. Google double angle formulas, half angle formulas so you can get correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

$\sec \theta = 
\frac 5 3 \iff \cos \theta = \frac 3 5$

$\sin \theta =-\sqrt{1-\cos^2 \theta}=-\frac4 5 $

1. You can find $\tan \theta=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$, and hence $\tan 2 \theta = \frac{2\tan \theta}{1-\tan^2 \theta}$.
2. $\tan \frac \theta 2 = \frac{\sin \theta}{1+\cos \theta}$
3. $\cos \theta = 2\cos^2 \frac \theta 2 -1$